# How to have dead keys working with an USB keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, usb-on-the-go

I've connected to my phone a desktop USB keyboard using an OTG connector. Everything works fine, unfortunately I  can't produce accented letters like áéíãê.

When I type an accent, like `'^, another symbol prints. I expected the behavior of a dead key, followed with the accented letter.

The keyboard has a Brazilian ABNT layout. I tested it with Google Gboard and Samsung standard keyboard. Tested with languages English international and Brazilian Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to avoid non-free software and found AnySoftKeyboard available thru F-Droid is able to handle dead keys too. Works well!

Answer (score -1):

Try using Swiftkey, because some other users on the Google Forum have reported that they also cannot type Accented letters, using Gboard.

If Swiftkey does not work, than unfortunately the problem is most likely that your keyboard does not support Accented characters on Android devices.

A keyboard that users have said supports accented characters on Android Devices is the Logitech K810.

Comment: Can you  link the forum post, please? I need it working with an usb keyboard, not a bluetooth one.

Comment: Yup, there were two forums - http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/rk3288-devices/beelink-3288-devices/20982-accents-and-physical-bluetooth-keyboard and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/Szp0HD7UK48;context-place=forum/nexus

Comment: Try Swiftkey with your current keyboard, chances are it may work.

Comment: @neves, Swiftkey is actually a good answer for your issue. I just tried it today and I can get accented letters in portuguese